# print prime number

Tags: php

Why this code doesn't work?

This code should print prime number
But Doesnt print
Whats the Problem???

```
<?php
$isprime = true;
$i = 2;
$j = 2;
while ($i <= 100) {
    while ($j <= 100) {
        if ($i != $j && $i % $j == 0) {
            $isprime = false;
            break;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    if ($isprime) {
        echo $i . "<br />";
    }
    $isprime = true;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: No. No it shouldn't.

Comment: you ever thought about moving the initialization of `$j` and `$isprime` inside the first while-loop?